# How to access programmatically a tableview added with storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I added a tableview to my viewcontroller using the storyboard.  What is actually happening behind the scenes?  If a UITableview object gets created how can I access this object programmatically?  What is the name of the instance?  Is it a property of my viewcontroller object?

More specifically, what I need to do is force my tableview to refresh (from inside of my viewcontroller).  I read in other posts that I should be able to do something like this [self.tableview reloadData].  I can't do this because my viewcontroller does not have a property called "tableview" (or anything similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control + click and drag your tableView into your header file to create an IBOutlet

[image]

Set the delegate and data source by control click and drag from your table view to your view controller - make sure both dots are seen. Now

[image]

In the interface .h file add the delegate and datasource as such:

```
@interface HomeTableViewController : UIViewController
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Now your view controller should have access to the methods needed to use [self.tableView reloadData]

Answer (score 0):

try this [simple table view](http://iosfirst.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-create-tableview-using.html)

and this [work with custom tableview cell](http://iosfirst.blogspot.com/2015/09/blog-post.html)

try above tutorials and in your case to use `[self.yourtablviewname reload]`
you have to create an `outlet` of your table view and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the storyboard defines a collection of objects which are created when you make an instance of say, a ViewController.

You are on the right track, you need to define variables in your view controller which are references to the objects in the storyboard. You mark them as IBOutlet in your code. You then 'connect' them to the objects in the storyboard. Right click on the viewcontroller in the storyboard and you will see the variables which have been designated as IBOutlet listed as 'outlets'. You can drag from the popup table to the objects in the storyboard to connect them. Now, when an ViewController is created, all the IBOutlet variables are set to point to the various objects (tables, text views etc) in the instance just created.

Remember that the 'connect' you do with the Interface Builder, happens at rum time when you create an instance of the object in IB.